# Receiving makefile argument in C source code

Tags: c, makefile

I want to call a makefile like so: make uj LOCATION=my_room and have my_room appear in printouts.

For example:

```
    print(" LOCATION is %s \n", LOCATION);
```

Should print LOCATION is my_room. If no LOCATION parameter is given, it should print undefined.

I've tried with the following.
In my makefile:

```
ifndef LOCATION
    LOCATION = "undefined"
endif

CFLAGS +=  -DLOCATION=$(LOCATION)
```

And then calling the above print function, but this throws compilation errors. I'm missing something. Can you help?

Edited:
Added the error during compilation.

```
    In file included from ../../uJ/cerberOS_BSP.h:4:0,
                 from ../../uJ/main_upnp.c:3:
../../uJ/main_upnp.c: In function ‘printDiagnostics’:
../../uJ/cerberOS_debug.h:15:59: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
 #define print(FORMAT,args...) printf_P(PSTR(FORMAT),##args)
                                                           ^
../../uJ/main_upnp.c:35:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘print’
  print(" LOCATION (as s) is %s \n", LOCATION);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "errors"? If you have build errors please include the build log in the question body (in full, complete and unedited).

Comment: Te easiest debug method would be to just pass your source through the preprocessor and see what's being generated at that location.

Comment: Apologies, added the error during compilation.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but what is the reason you use macros and custom functions for printing? It will make the code less maintainable and harder to read and understand.

Comment: The problem, I think, is *how* you use [variadic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro).

Answer (score 3):

The quotes for the string are missing, so it will expand to

`print(" LOCATION is %s \n", undefined);`

Try:

`CFLAGS +=  -DLOCATION=\"$(LOCATION)\"`

This will expand to

`print(" LOCATION is %s \n", "undefined");`

which is what you want.